# "Paused on exception: DOMException" when browsing websites with the console open

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've been experiencing this issue for some time now and can't find any answers online so I thought I'd create this question and hopefully it helps some others too.

If I pop open the console in Google Chrome and reload a page, it will often show me an error with `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and `jquery.min.js`. The error reads:

> Paused on exception: DOMException

Sometimes I also get this error in `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` on certain sites, and sometimes in `analytics.js`.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Does my browser have a corrupt version of jQuery installed or something?

Comment: Lots of `Paused on exception: DOMException`

Comment: Which browser are you using? There was a bug filed for this referencing the Chrome browser about a year ago http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11478

Comment: @JoeBuckle Chrome `Version 28.0.1500.71`

Comment: @JoeBuckle That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! If you want credit, happy to give it. Just leave the answer below

Comment: btw, jQuery is not 'installed in your browser', it is just a javascript framework that get's loaded along with the rest of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

The **Paused on exception: DOMException** error is a jQuery/Chrome bug and a ticket was filed about a year ago.

It is rectified by following the steps in the change history part of the report below.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11478

Comment: It's not a bug - that bug report was correctly closed as invalid. There's nothing wrong with jQuery performing actions that can cause exceptions, and then catching those exceptions. Chrome's behavior is also correct - it only does this if you've explicitly turned on the "Pause on all exceptions" option. (Admittedly, it's very easy to misclick and turn that option on accidentally, and pretty non-obvious, if you're unfamiliar with the debugger, what the heck is causing the apparent errors - which is bad design.)

Comment: OK I'll correct this answer unless you want to give the right one?

Comment: This did help me find a way to resolve the problem. It was getting very annoying considering it wasn't my code generating the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be caused by having the Chrome devtools set to *"Pause On Caught Exceptions"*. In old versions of Chrome, it was easy to accidentally put the devtools into this state since it could be cycled into just by clicking repeatedly on the unlabelled hexagonal pause icon in the Sources tab, which used to cycle between three states: "Pause On All Exceptions", "Pause On Uncaught Exceptions", and "Don't Pause On Exceptions".

In newer versions of Chrome, this UI deficiency has been corrected by making pausing on *caught* exceptions require checking an explicitly labelled checkbox that appears after "Pause on exceptions" mode is entered, both circled in red below:

[image: screenshot]